# What invokves the 2nd function call when using React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I wrote the following React exercise which uses no hooks and renders a button.

```js
const Button = ({ onClick }) => <button onClick={onClick}>Do Nothing</button>;

const Base = () => {
  const onClickFunction = (() => {
    console.log("Creating OnClick Function");
    return () => {};
  })();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <Button onClick={onClickFunction} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

onClickFunction uses a self-invoking function, so that I can place a `console.log` to see the following behaviour.  In this example, when Base is rendered, the message *Creating OnClick Function* appears only once

If I change `Base` to the following however, adding a hook usage:

```js
const Button = ({ onClick }) => <button onClick={onClick}>Do Nothing</button>;

const Base = () => {
  const notUsedRef = React.useRef();

  const onClickFunction = (() => {
    console.log("Creating OnClick Function");
    return () => {};
  })();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <Button onClick={onClickFunction} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

You will see the *Creating OnClick Function* message twice.

This CodeSandbox illustrates what I've been seeing: https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-forest-99clo?file=/src/App.js

---

- Using React DevTools Profiler, we can see there is no rerender of this component.
- Using `<React.Profiler`, it reports this component also didn't *update*.

I know that using `React.useCallback` wouldn't trigger a second invokation, however the question would still stand why we are in the situation Base is called twice.

My question is: why and what is triggering Base to be invoked when there is no need for a rerender.

Comment: Even more curious: onClickFunction is getting created twice, this should have triggered onClick to get a new prop and cause a rerender Button, but we can see within React DevTools Profiler it only mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way React implements hooks.
If you invoke any hook, even if you don't use the resulting value, you are telling React to render twice before mounting, even if the props don't change. You can substitute the usage of useRef by useState, useEffect, etc. Try below.

You can also wrap your component with React.memo. Every function defined inside the function is recreated in every render.

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-water-y18w0?file=/src/App.js

**EDIT:** Only happens during development and in components wrapped by React.StrictMode. In the words of **gaearon**:

> It's an intentional feature of the StrictMode. This only happens in
> development, and helps find accidental side effects put into the
> render phase. We only do this for components with Hooks because those
> are more likely to accidentally have side effects in the wrong place.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for a more specific and accurate answer. More accurately, it's the standard React Hooks that trigger this, however, not all Hooks will cause this:  `const UseNothing => () => 0` for example, will not trigger this.  I'm looking at what specifically causes this, within React.

Comment: It turns out to be a feature of strict mode. I edited the answer. By the way, defining **const UseNothing => () => 0** inside a function does not generate a hook. Custom hooks must, ultimately, be composed of primitive hooks (useState, useRef, etc).

Comment: Nice! That Issue is exactly what I was looking for!